# Kafka Producer Warnings WARN [kafka-producer-network-thread ]

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am seeing below WARN in my Kafka producer.

```
WARN [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-4] o.a.k.c.NetworkClient 
[NetworkClient.java:588] Connection to node -1 could not be 
established. Broker may not be available.
```

Kafka Client version = 0.11.0.1
Kafka Broker version is same as client Version.

My Data is flowing into the kafka cluster and I am able to consume as well. But I am keep getting this errors. Any clues >\?

Comment: post your code, check did you configure correct bootstrap-servers are not?

Comment: @Deadpool Yes my bootstrap-servers are correct, In fact I am able to connect to other kafka brokers and data is flowing as well.

Comment: Not really enough information here to help. There is some network property misconfigured or one of your brokers is not running

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 all the brokers are running fine. Other producers work correctly, In the producer which I created all the properties are default except for bootstrap.servers which I set it to broker names. Brokers are ssl enabled.

Comment: Well, it does say `Broker may not be available` and `node -1` means the client cannot connect to at least one of the brokers.

Comment: @cricket_007 I am able to telnet to broker on 9092 port from client so network connectivity doesn't look like issue. Do you think of any other place ?

Comment: One server port being open doesn't really give the full picture. The actual full list of brokers is given to your clients from Zookeeper